# The norm of isotropic sub-Gaussian random vector may not be sub-Gaussian

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is a isotropic sub-Gaussian $n$-dimensional random vector (i.e. $EXX^T=I_n$, and for any unit vector $u$,$\|\left<X,u\right>\|_{\psi_2}\le K$). It is said that $\|X\|_2-\sqrt n$ may not be sub-Gaussian with bounded norm $CK$ which does not depend on $n$. But I havn't found a counter example.

When $X$ is a uniform ball distribution or a uniform hypercube distribution, it can both be proved that $\|X\|_2-\sqrt n$ is sub-Gaussian. Moreover, if $X_i$ are independent, the proposition is also true.

Can someone show a counter example? Thank you!

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let 
\begin{equation}
 \mu_X=\tfrac12\,\mu_{aZ}+\tfrac12\,\mu_{bZ}, 
\end{equation}
where $\mu_U$ denotes the probability distribution of a random vector $U$, $Z\sim N(0,I_n)$, 
and $a,b$ are constants such that
\begin{equation}
 0<a<1<b\quad\text{and}\quad \tfrac12\,a^2+\tfrac12\,b^2=1. 
\end{equation}

Then $EXX^T=I_n$. Also, for any unit vector $u$ and real $s>0$
\begin{equation}
 E\exp\{\left<X,u\right>^2/s^2\}=\frac1{2\sqrt{1-2a^2/s^2}}+\frac1{2\sqrt{1-2b^2/s^2}}<2 
\end{equation}
if $s$ is large enough (depending only on $a,b$), 
so that, by the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-Gaussian_distribution) of $\|\cdot\|_{\psi_2}\|$, we have $\|\left<X,u\right>\|_{\psi_2}\le s$. For instance, here we can take $a=1/5,b=7/5,s=3$.

On the other hand, for
\begin{equation}
 t:=(b-1)\sqrt{n}/2,  
\end{equation} 
\begin{multline}
 2\,Ee^{(\|X\|-\sqrt n)^2/t^2}>Ee^{(\|bZ\|-\sqrt n)^2/t^2}
 >Ee^{(\|bZ\|-\sqrt n)^2/t^2}1_{\|Z\|^2>n} \\ 
 >e^{(b\sqrt n-\sqrt n)^2/t^2}\,P(\|Z\|^2>n)=e^4\,P(\|Z\|^2>n)\to e^4/2>4, 
\end{multline}
because, by the central limit theorem, $P(\|Z\|^2>n)\to1/2$. 
So, for all large enough $n$, 
\begin{equation}
 \|\|X\|-\sqrt n\|_{\psi_2}\ge t=(b-1)\sqrt{n}/2\to\infty,
\end{equation}
as desired.

Comment: This construction is really clever!

Answer (score 2):

> It is said that $\|X\|_2-\sqrt n$ may not be sub-Gaussian.

Who says that? It is sub-Gaussian.

Let $a_i = \|\langle X,e_i\rangle\|_{\psi_2}$, $i=1,\dots,n$. Then for $a > \sqrt{n}\max_{1\le i\le n} a_i$ we have
$$
\mathrm E[e^{\|X\|^2_2/a^2}] = \mathrm E\biggl[\prod_{i=1}^n e^{\langle X,e_i\rangle^2_2/a^2}\biggr] \le \biggl(\prod_{i=1}^n \mathrm E [e^{n\langle X,e_i\rangle^2_2/a^2}] \biggr)^{1/n}\le \biggl(\prod_{i=1}^n \mathrm E [e^{\langle X,e_i\rangle^2_2/a_i^2}] \biggr)^{1/n}  \le 2,
$$
whence 
$$
\bigl\|\|X\|_2\bigr\|_{\psi_2}\le \sqrt{n}\max_{1\le i\le n} \|\langle X,e_i\rangle\|_{\psi_2}.
$$

Comment: Oh, it's not this meaning. It should mean that fix $\|X\|_{\psi_2}=K$, $\|\|X\|_2-\sqrt n\|_{\psi_2}$ can still be arbitraily large (that is, it depends on $n$). But when $X_i$ are independent, $\|\|X\|_2-\sqrt n\|_{\psi_2}$ can be bounded by constant.

Comment: In the book "high-dimensional probability" written by Roman Vershynin, page 60, 3.4.10.

Comment: But the statement in Vershynin is very different! He does not say that the norm isn't sub-Gaussian. He says that the inequality of Thm 3.1.1 does not hold in general (with absolute constant). As you see, the constant we get here depends on dimension.

Comment: Yes, I think so, too. But I cannot find an example that the norm depends on $n$. I tried high-demension ball and hypercube. I cannot come up with other isotropic high dimensional distributions which are easy to calculate the norm. You give an upper bound, but how to show the bound can be reached?

Comment: This is a different question. As originally asked, the question currently is answered. You might want to ask the exact question about dependence on $n$ separately; editing question after the answer appeared is not a good idea. Also I believe your question(s) is(are) more suitable for [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I am really sorry that my description for the question is not clear enough.